# do i need to use django reset_queries()

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models, memory-leaks

i am using django 1.3 and i am running a script outside of a web context (from command line).
my code keep reading 10000 entries from the db each time.
i noticed that the memory usage of the process is getting bigger over time.
my code is:

```
def getData(startIndex,chunkSize):
    dataList =Mydata.objects.filter(update_date__isnull = True)[startIndex:startIndex+chunkSize]
    return list(dataList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   chunkSize = 10000
   startIndex = 0
   dataSize = Mydata.objects.filter(update_date__isnull = True).count()
   while startIndex < dataSize:
       dataList = getData(startIndex,chunkSize)
       startIndex += chunkSize
       do_stuff(dataList)
```

my question is: do i need to use `reset_queries()` and or `connection.close()`
and is this is the reason for the increase in memory usage ?

Comment: just to check: do you have `DEBUG = False`?

Comment: is it definitely the python process that is eating more memory? can you step through the script and see which lines are causing memory hikes

Comment: yes it is the python process that takes the memory.but it may not be the query part, it could be the do_stuff part, i just want to be sure that reset_queries() is not needed

Comment: Also, try to use `queryset.iterator()` instead of `list(queryset)` to explicitly only read one record at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with using [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) or [defer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer) methods in your query. These two are used to retrieve only the fields that you actually need, instead of all fields. Your query will be slightly faster and consume less memory, because not needed fields will not be fetched from  the database.